# How to store file after editing in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have text file. I do editing for the file, after finish editing I want to store the data and overwrite the file with editing.

```
My file
***********************************
;ML=DPC
;CRM=AE
;**********************************
```

---

```
Function CRM
{
    Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $CRM
    #parameter(mandatory=$true)] $Variable_Name
    )

$filteredContent = (Get-Content $FilePath) -replace '^;' -replace '\\','\\' |
    Where-Object{-not $_.startswith('*')} 
$information = [pscustomobject]($filteredContent -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData)


$CRM_1 = $information.CRM
$CRM_Edit = "$CRM"
$CRM_Edit | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Force
}
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

My expectation after editing the value of `CRM` to `AFF` ,  I will have a text file like this.

```
***********************************
;ML=DPC
;CRM=AFF
;**********************************
```

Comment: All your function does, is writing the passed parameter `-CRM` to the file passed with `-FilePath`. As you don't show how  you use the function you really should read what a [mcve] is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your function because although the `ConvertFrom-Stringdata` is nice for reading, it seems cumbersome here to write data back to a file in the format you want. You also hard coded the "CRM" string in your function, which makes `ConvertFrom-Stringdata` less powerful. Here is an example using the "CRM" hard coded string.

```
Function CRM
{
    Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $CRM
    )

$FileContents = Get-Content $FilePath
$FileContents -replace "^(?<1>;CRM=).*","`${1}$CRM" | Set-Content $FilePath

}
```

Executing the function above:

```
CRM $filepath "AFF"
Get-Content $filepath
***********************************
;ML=DPC
;CRM=AFF
;**********************************
```

An alternative function that will update the value of any key in your file content format is the following:

```
Function Update-Value
{
    Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $Key,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $Value
    )

$FileContents = Get-Content $FilePath
$FileContents -replace "^(?<1>;$Key=).*","`${1}$Value" | Set-Content $FilePath

}
```

The output from running the function above:

```
Get-Content $filepath
***********************************
;ML=DPC
;CRM=AE
;**********************************

Update-Value $filepath "CRM" "AFF"
Update-Value $filepath "ML" "NewML"

Get-Content $filepath
***********************************
;ML=NewML
;CRM=AFF
;**********************************
```

If I were to augment your function, maintain using `ConvertFrom-Stringdata`, while changing as little as possible, I'd do something like the following:

```
Function CRM
{
    Param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)]$FilePath,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)] $CRM
    #parameter(mandatory=$true)] $Variable_Name
    )

$FileContents = Get-Content $FilePath
$filteredContent = $FileContents -replace '^;' -replace '\\','\\' |
    Where-Object{-not $_.startswith('*')} 
$information = [pscustomobject]($filteredContent -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData)

$information.CRM = $CRM
$informationFormatted = ForEach ($p in $information.psobject.properties) {
    ";{0}={1}" -f $p.name,$p.value
    }
$FileContents[0],$informationFormatted,$FileContents[-1] | Set-Content $filepath
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `-replace` operator is doing all the work. The text to be replaced `^(;$Key=).*` uses a Regex match mechanism. `^` indicates the beginning of a line. The parentheses creates a capture group that can be accessed in the substitution string as `$1`. `;` and `=` are literal matches. `$Key` gets replaced with the value of the `$Key` parameter from the function call. `.*` is all characters until the end of the current line. `$1$Value` is the substitution regex. `$1` is what is captured in the capture group 1 noted by `()` in the matching string. `$Value` is the value of the `$Value` parameter when the function is called. `$1` is backtick escaped so that PowerShell will not attempt to expand it as a string variable. It is a regex specific language element that represents a replacement pattern and not a typical variable. The reason `$Key` and `$Value` are evaluated as variables is because they exist between double quotes (`"`) and are not escaped.